# What is the purpose of "spring-boot-starter-integration" dependency?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-boot-starter

I am refactoring a legacy Spring boot project which implements Spring integration. In one of the module, I have removed the following dependency to fix the CVE-2019-3772 vulnerability. The projects still compile and run without any failures. I have checked the source code and none of the imports uses this dependency.

So, what is the use of this dependency?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-integration</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Still, the module uses the following integration dependencies.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-integration-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-integration-http</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The starter simply pulls in `spring-integraition-core` and `spring-aop`, which are also transitive dependencies of your other spring integration deps; so it is redundant.